# Strategy to use Selenium browser testing with Flutter Web apps

Tags: selenium, flutter, automated-tests, flutter-web

Flutter Web does not assign css classes or id's to generated html elements meaning you cannot use the normal approach for Selenium to find elements, for example to press a button.

See for example [How do we add selectors/ids to Flutter widgets so they can be accessed from Appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55499515/how-do-we-add-selectors-ids-to-flutter-widgets-so-they-can-be-accessed-from-appi)

Flutter Driver seems quite limited: [Advanced features with Flutter Driver (or Silenium/Ghost Inspector)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62615379/advanced-features-with-flutter-driver-or-silenium-ghost-inspector)